# How to save commands output into a variable via ssh in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I want to save an output of a piped sequence of commands into a variable on a remote server. I'm trying to do it via ssh like this:

```
ssh $host "kernel_ver=`sudo yum list kernel --showduplicates | grep 7.$os_rel | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2 | head -n1`; echo $kernel_ver"
```

I'm getting this errors:

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
ssh: Could not resolve hostname kernel_ver= ; echo : Name or service not known
```

$os_rel is a variable in my script containing a number.

I tried different syntax like:  "$( )" to capture the output and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The question is 100% on topic. Most bash questions are fine. The ones that aren't are purely interactive questions like "how do I change my keybindings?" or "how do I color my prompt?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double quotes to surround everything then the backticks will be evaluated by the local shell rather than the remote one. So will the variable reference `$kernel_ver`. Use single quotes to disable both.

```
ssh $host 'kernel_ver=`sudo yum list kernel --showduplicates | grep 7.$os_rel | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2 | head -n1`; echo $kernel_ver'
```

If `$os_rel` is a local variable that you *do* want expanded then you'll need to temporarily leave single quotes.

```
ssh $host 'kernel_ver=`sudo yum list kernel --showduplicates | grep 7.'"$os_rel"' | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2 | head -n1`; echo $kernel_ver'
```